# CMake Windows find_package Imported target "..." includes non-existent path

Tags: c++, cmake

I am creating my own package that configures, builds and installs the package without problem including cmake files.

The source files are here:
https://github.com/petrasvestartas/CMAKE/tree/main/install_export

Installation procedure build SHARED libs like this:

```
cmake  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64  ..  && cmake  --build . --config Release && cmake  --install .
```

I see the files here after installation:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\
│   sortdemo-config-release.cmake
│   sortdemo-config.cmake
│
├───include
│   ├───print
│   │       print.hpp
│   │
│   └───sort
│           sort.hpp
│
└───lib
        my_print_lib.dll
        my_print_lib.lib
        my_sort_lib.dll
        my_sort_lib.lib
```

Now I want to use this package to another simple project:
https://github.com/petrasvestartas/CMAKE/blob/main/find_package/CMakeLists.txt

But I get an error:

```
Imported target "my_sort_lib" includes non-existent path -> include/sort files
```

MY SIMPLE QUESTION:
**How to know where CMake searches for the files?**

Since I have created the project I could modify the path, but I do not know where the problem is.

[image]

Comment: Contrary to the error message you posted as text, the actual error message shown in the screenshot shows you using the absolute path `/include/sort` which of course does not match the path of the include dir in your installation. You should use a file relative to the file containing the logic, e.g. `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/sort`...

Comment: A quick look at your project shows that you're hardcoding absolute paths using by using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in your `CMakeLists.txt` file. This should be avoided, since there is logic like the `--prefix` option of `cmake --install` or `cpack` that rely on being able to adjust the target path independent of the project configuration.

Comment: This is not correct. I am not modifying it, since everything gets installed into C:/ProgramFiles/ProjectName.
It would be good if someone could try to test this project. It is very basic Hello World like example.

Comment: Maybe you are not modifying the variable and don't intend to use the `--prefix` option for overriding the install location, but if you publish a project, the users may want to do this and even if you don't publish the sources, you may e.g. want to generate a e.g. a `.deb` or even just a `.tar.gz` file for your project in the future which internally does use this logic to build the file structure for the target system inside the binary dir. If you hardcode `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, the files are given absolute path possibly overriding an existing installation which should be avoided.

Comment: Can you show a full proper way of doing this without CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX?
I am struggling with this for days...

Comment: Instead of `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:/include/sort>` ([install_export/src/sort/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/petrasvestartas/CMAKE/blob/main/install_export/src/sort/CMakeLists.txt#L11)you probably wanted `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/sort>`. In any case, it is requirement of the Stack Overflow for the code to be in the **question post**, not *linked*.

Comment: @tsyvarev Thank you very much! It works!
It does not copy the shared libraries but after manual copy it runs.
How can I accept your reply as an answer?
And do you know why the .dlls are not copied?